# difference between two timestamps (in days) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT MIN (snap_id) AS FIRST_SNAP,
     MAX (snap_id) AS LAST_SNAP,
     MIN (BEGIN_INTERVAL_TIME) AS FIRST_QUERY,
     MAX (END_INTERVAL_TIME) AS LAST_QUERY,
     max(end_interval_time) - min(begin_interval_time) as "TIME_ELAPSED"
FROM dba_hist_snapshot
ORDER BY snap_id;

2931    3103    5/28/2012 6:00:11.065 AM    6/4/2012 11:00:40.967 AM    +07 05:00:29.902000
```

I would like the last columns output to be 7 (for the days). I have tried  trunc and extract like some other posts mentioned but can't seem to get the syntax right.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from your comment, you're using `timestamp` columns, not `datetime`.  You could use `extract` to retrieve the hour difference, and then `trunc(.../24)` to get the whole number of days:

```
trunc(extract(hour from max(end_interval_time) - min(begin_interval_time))/24)
```

Or you could cast the `timestamp` to a `date`:

```
trunc(cast(max(end_interval_time) as date) -
    cast(min(begin_interval_time) as date))
```

Comment: This is one I tried and gives me an error. "inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND"

Comment: The extract method didn't seem to work. It was only outputting "5" which is the difference between the two times in hours(did not take into account the different days). The casting method worked though! Thanks for the help!